# How do I Perform Inner Join on 2 XML tables to get 1 nested table using XSLT?

Tags: xml, xslt

i have 3 XML Table ITAB, TAB and TAB1. ITAB has operations value for which we have details in TAB.

```
    <root>


        <ITAB>
        <DATA>
            <OPERATION>O_WORK_ORDER_1</OPERATION>
        </DATA>
        <DATA>
        <OPERATION>O_WORK_ORDER_2</OPERATION>
        </DATA>
    </ITAB>

    <TAB>
        <DATA>
            <OPERATION>O_WORK_ORDER_1</OPERATION>
            <WORKINSTRUCTION>CASCADION</WORKINSTRUCTION>
            <CODE>CODEXX1</CODE>
            <REVISION>111REV1</REVISION>
        </DATA>
        <DATA>
            <OPERATION>O_WORK_ORDER_1</OPERATION>
            <WORKINSTRUCTION>CASCADION</WORKINSTRUCTION>
            <CODE>CODEXX1</CODE>
            <REVISION>111REV1</REVISION>
        </DATA>

        <DATA>
            <OPERATION>O_WORK_ORDER_2</OPERATION>
            <WORKINSTRUCTION>CASCADION2</WORKINSTRUCTION>
            <CODE>CODEXX2</CODE>
            <REVISION>111REV2</REVISION>
        </DATA>
    </TAB>

    <TAB1>
        <DATA>
            <OPERATION>O_WORK_ORDER_1</OPERATION>
            <DCPARAMETER>TESTPARAMETER1</DCPARAMETER>
            <DCVALUE>TEMP111</DCVALUE>
            <DCRESULT>PASS</DCRESULT>
        </DATA>
        <DATA>
            <OPERATION>O_WORK_ORDER_2</OPERATION>
            <DCPARAMETER>TESTPARAMETER2</DCPARAMETER>
            <DCVALUE>TEMP112</DCVALUE>
            <DCRESULT>FAIL</DCRESULT>
        </DATA>
    </TAB1>

</root>
```

we want to Perform a inner join on TAB table for the Values in ITAB table. eg- for this case we must have an output as a row containing Operation value and a table from TAB containing all the data sets of that operation value.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="/">
  <html>
<body>


    <table border="1">
      <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
      <th>OPERATION</th>  
      <th>Table</th>
    </tr>
    <xsl:for-each select="ITAB/DATA">

      <tr>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="OPERATION"/></td>  
        <xsl:variable name="Operation" select="OPERATION"/>     
        <td><xsl:apply-templates select="OPERATION"></td>
      </tr>

    </xsl:for-each>
    </table>

</body>
</html>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="OPERATION">
    <table border="1">
      <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
      <th>OPERATION</th>
      <th>WORKINSTRUCTION</th>
      <th>REVISION</th>      
    </tr>
    <xsl:for-each select="TAB/DATA">
    <xsl:if test="OPERATION={$Operation}">
      <tr>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="OPERATION"/></td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="WORKINSTRUCTION"/></td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="REVISION"/></td>        
      </tr>
    </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
    </table>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

we tried this but it failed can anybody help. and can i display the Variable value directly on the Screen. Is there any other approach i can follow to achieve this.

Comment: Use a **[key](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xslt-19991116#key)** to resolve cross-references.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am afraid there are quite a few issues with your XSLT, although none are hard to resolve...

1. In your template matching `/`, you do `<xsl:for-each select="ITAB/DATA">`, but `/` matches the document node, which is the parent of your `root` element. Consequently your select clause will not select anything. You should change the template to match `/root` (or just `root` instead)
2. The XSLT is not well-formed XML, as you do `<xsl:apply-templates select="OPERATION">` which is not closed. It should be `<xsl:apply-templates select="OPERATION" />`
3. Variables are local to the block in which they are declared, so your current declaration of `$Operation` will actually only available with the `<tr>...</tr>` block. You can actually just move the declaration into the template matching `OPERATION` (where it would need to become `<xsl:variable name="Operation" select="."/>` as you the current node would be `OPERATION` at this point.
4. `<xsl:if test="OPERATION={$Operation}">` is not valid syntax. It should be just `<xsl:if test="OPERATION=$Operation">` because XSLT would already be expecting an expression here.
5. In fact, you don't need the `xsl:if` at all, because you can add it to the `xsl:for-each` like so... `<xsl:for-each select="TAB/DATA[OPERATION=$Operation]">`
6. Actually, this won't work either, because you are currently matching the `OPERATION` node nested in an `ITAB` element, and this does not have `TAB` as a child. You really want to select `TAB/DATA` elsewhere in the document. So, you should do `<xsl:for-each select="//TAB/DATA[OPERATION=$Operation]">`

Try this XSLT....

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="root">
 <html>
  <body>
   <table border="1">
    <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
     <th>OPERATION</th>  
     <th>Table</th>
    </tr>
    <xsl:for-each select="ITAB/DATA">
     <tr>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="OPERATION"/></td>  
      <td><xsl:apply-templates select="OPERATION" /></td>
     </tr>
    </xsl:for-each>
   </table>
  </body>
 </html>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="OPERATION">
 <xsl:variable name="Operation" select="."/>     
 <table border="1">
  <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
   <th>OPERATION</th>
   <th>WORKINSTRUCTION</th>
   <th>REVISION</th>      
  </tr>
  <xsl:for-each select="//TAB/DATA[OPERATION=$Operation]">
   <tr>
    <td><xsl:value-of select="OPERATION"/></td>
    <td><xsl:value-of select="WORKINSTRUCTION"/></td>
    <td><xsl:value-of select="REVISION"/></td>        
   </tr>
  </xsl:for-each>
 </table>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Having said that, as mentioned in comments, it is much better to use an `xsl:key` to look up data from other parts of the XML document.

So, define a key like so:

```
<xsl:key name="tabs" match="TAB/DATA" use="OPERATION" />
```

And get the relevant nodes like so...

```
<xsl:for-each select="key('tabs', $Operation)">
```

Actually, you don't really need to use a variable here. Try this XSLT too:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:key name="tabs" match="TAB/DATA" use="OPERATION" />

<xsl:template match="root">
 <html>
  <body>
   <table border="1">
    <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
     <th>OPERATION</th>  
     <th>Table</th>
    </tr>
    <xsl:for-each select="ITAB/DATA">
     <tr>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="OPERATION"/></td>  
      <td><xsl:apply-templates select="OPERATION" /></td>
     </tr>
    </xsl:for-each>
   </table>
  </body>
 </html>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="OPERATION">
 <table border="1">
  <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
   <th>OPERATION</th>
   <th>WORKINSTRUCTION</th>
   <th>REVISION</th>      
  </tr>
  <xsl:for-each select="key('tabs', .)">
   <tr>
    <td><xsl:value-of select="OPERATION"/></td>
    <td><xsl:value-of select="WORKINSTRUCTION"/></td>
    <td><xsl:value-of select="REVISION"/></td>        
   </tr>
  </xsl:for-each>
 </table>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

See it in action at http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/pPqsHUi

Comment: Thanks for your help. Much needed effort.